# combo box and Generic list

Tags: c#

I'm Having a list

```
 List<string> strArraylist = new List<string>();
```

i want to add to it the values of a **combo box** ..

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**: I just realize you may have been asking the *opposite* of what I provided below: how to added the items *from* a `ComboBox` *to* a `List<string>`. If that's the case, you could always do it like this:

```
List<string> strList = new List<string>();
strList.AddRange(cbx.Items.Cast<object>().Select(x => x.ToString()));
```

---

Here's an extension method I use:

```
public static class ControlHelper
{
    public static void Populate<T>(this ComboBox comboBox, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        try
        {
            comboBox.BeginUpdate();
            foreach (T item in items)
            {
                comboBox.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            comboBox.EndUpdate();
        }
    }
}
```

This allows you to populate a `ComboBox` with any generic collection that can be enumerated. See how easy it is to call:

```
List<string> strList = new List<string> { "abc", "def", "ghi" };
cbx.Populate(strList);
```

Notice that you could also make this method non-generic, since the `ComboBox.Items` property is of a non-generic type (you can add any `object` to `Items`). In this case the `Populate` method would accept a plain `IEnumerable` instead of an `IEnumerable<T>`.